# get circle center coordinate

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have the next code for getting the coords for a polygon, but I would like to get the center coordinates when I draw a circle.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Best regards and hope someone knows something about it.

```
function draw() { 
 if (drawingManager <= 0) then 

var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
  drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
  drawingControl: true,
  drawingControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
    drawingModes: [
      google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
     google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
      google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
     google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
     google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
    ]
  },
  markerOptions: {
    icon: 'images/beachflag.png'
  },
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#1E90FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    clickable: true,
    editable: true,
    zIndex: 1
  }
});


var coord_listener = google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());


alert(coordinates);
PassPolygonToField(coordinates);
window.poly = polygon;
});



drawingManager.setMap(map);


} 

function PassPolygonToField(coordinates) {
//here I pass the coords to the form field and then I insert the form into a mysql database.
document.getElementById('myField').value = (coordinates);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code after the coord_listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function(circle) {
  alert(circle.getCenter());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and I had to use :

```
const lat = circle.overlay.getCenter().lat()
const lng = circle.overlay.getCenter().lng()
```